# Intermittent 502 Bad Gateway errors running Express apps behind Nginx

Tags: node.js, angularjs, nginx, express

I'm currently running a range of Node.js express apps behind nginx. However although I have got the apps up running fine I am now experiencing intermittent 502 Bad Gateway errors in certain circumstances.

The main instance is where a user attempts to login. Often the first attempt to login will return a 502 error (and this error will be instantaneous rather than happening after a delay) whereas the second attempt immediately thereafter will process fine, with no change in the request headers.

I have examined the logs for nginx and express and it appears that in the first instance despite details being identical, the first attempt returns a 500 error (as is planned in the case of a bad login attempt). This then triggers a 502 error in nginx.

**Nginx error log:**

```
2013/10/21 19:32:57 [error] 8178#0: *32101 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 82.40.77.228, server: instok.net, request: "POST /login HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://127.0.0.1:5001/login", host: "instok.net", referrer: "https://instok.net/"
```

**Nginx access log:**

```
- [21/Oct/2013:19:32:57 +0000] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 502 172 "https://instok.net/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0" "-"82.40.77.228 - 
- [21/Oct/2013:19:32:59 +0000] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 200 5 "https://instok.net/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0" "-"82.40.77.228 -
```

**Express access log:**

```
- [Mon, 21 Oct 2013 19:32:57 GMT] \"POST /login HTTP/1.0\" 500 69 \"https://instok.net/\" 
- [Mon, 21 Oct 2013 19:32:59 GMT] \"POST /login HTTP/1.0\" 200 - \"https://instok.net/\"
```

**Server-side authentication**

```
function authenticate(name, pass, fn) {

  User.findOne({_id: name}, function(err, user) {
   if (!user) {  return fn(new Error("Cannot find user"))}; 

   bcrypt.compare(pass, user.hash, function(err, res){
     if (err || !res) { return fn(err) }

     else {
        return fn(null, user);
        }
    })
  })
}

exports.logIn = function(req, res){
 authenticate(req.body.username, req.body.password, function(err, user){
  if (user){
      req.session.regenerate(function(){
        req.session.user = user;
        res.status(200).send();
      })
  }
  else {
    res.status(500).send({message: "Error with username or password - please try again"})
  }

 });
}
```

The relevant parts of my nginx.conf file are at https://gist.github.com/grabbeh/6721046 and I also run several other node.js apps using the same file.

On the client-side I use Angular.js and $http.post to send the login details to the server, with conditional processing depending on whether a 200 or 500 error is sent back from the server.

I also use routeChangeError event to redirect on a 500 error from the server to redirect to a login page where a route is attempted to be accessed outside of login. However I don't think the client-side processing is of relevance as the error is returned prior to any client-side processing.

It may well be that there is a better way of handling authentication which may of course be a solution to the above issue, however at present I would like to get to the bottom of the intermittent 502 error.

The error does seem to originate from Express returning 500 when it should return 200 but I can't identify the issue despite playing around with the code. Any input would be gratefully received. The app itself is running at `https://instok.net` where all the client-side code can be viewed.

Out of interest the details for 502 and valid requests are below:

[image: 502]
[image: Valid request]

**EDIT**

The point I was missing was that I use https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever to keep the app running in the event of a crash. Having inspected the Forever logs it became clear the issue was that there was a failure to connect to a MongoDB database resulting in the app crashing. This error wasn't caught in the app and so, as I understand it, wasn't referenced in the Express logs. That has now been remedied, plus I've switched to another MongoDB instance which I hope will remedy matters.

Comment: To be honest I am not familiar with nginx, but something you should indeed change is that 500 error on your code. 50x means the server is broken; what you should send in case the username/password do not match is a 40x error, most probably a 401 that means Unauthorized. Check that and see if your flow improves.

Comment: Also, instead of an edit, it would be nice if you reply yourself and mark the question as responded if you no longer need an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I've found the issue which was that there was an uncaught error resulting from mongoose failing to connect to a MongoDB instance. I've now handled the error plus switched the database to a different instance. Touch wood, I'm not having any further issues at present.